# Json does not popup as download file in cakephp 2.3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am using cakephp 2.3 and want to generate list of users in json format.

controller name: users
method: list

Earlier, I have done it in cake 1.3.x and when user tries access method via url in browser then output comes as download file but when i am doing it in cakephp 2.3 then it is showing me json output on browser page itself instead of download file.

here is my code:

Controller:

```
<?php
      App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
class UsersController extends AppController {
      public $helpers = array('Form', 'Html', 'Js', 'Time');
      public $components = array('RequestHandler');
      var $layout = 'js/default';

public function list() {
            $this->log("i got data in user add:");
        $this->log($this->request->data);
        $posts['id']['name']='kapil';
        $this->set(compact('posts'));

    }
}
```

list.ctp file

```
<?php echo json_encode(compact('posts')); ?>
```

view/js/default.ctp

```
<?php echo $scripts_for_layout; ?>
<?php echo $this->fetch('content'); ?>
```

when i try to access my function in browser then i get this output

```
url: http://localhost/project/users/list

{"posts":{"id":{"name":"aditya"}}}
```

This output is correct but should come in download file format. I don't know what is wrong here.

Comment: Do you want to force the browser to download the file instead of rendering it?

Comment: yes! i want to download it

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to force download, your code must make use of Response object.

Here is an example taken from [CsvExport Behavior](http://www.pronique.com/blog/csvexport-behavior-for-cakephp-2):

```
   public function export() {
        $this->autoRender = false;
        $modelClass = $this->modelClass;
        $this->response->type('Content-Type: text/csv');
        $this->response->download( strtolower( Inflector::pluralize( $modelClass ) ) . '.csv' );
        $this->response->body( $this->$modelClass->exportCSV() );
    }
```

So your code would look like this :

```
   public function list() {

        $this->autoRender = false;

        $this->log("i got data in user add:");
        $this->log($this->request->data);

        $posts['id']['name']='kapil';
        $this->set(compact('posts'));
        $modelClass = $this->modelClass;

        $this->response->type('Content-Type: application/json');
        $this->response->download('list.json');
    }
```

Hope this helps!